# input data not posting to database

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an issue where I have three fields and two out of the three are posting to the database. I'll post my code below and see if you can help me out.

If you'd like the full code preview it can be found at:
http://github.com/mikerodham/chatty

I am following the Social Network tutorial by CodeCourse/PHPAcademy and this is just a weird error I've stumbled upon.

Yes I've checked if the username field in the database is spelt correctly!

**VIEW**

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('auth.signup') }}">

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">Your email address</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ Request::old('email') ?: '' }}">
      @if ($errors->has('email'))
          <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="username" class="control-label">Your desired username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ Request::old('username') ?: '' }}">
      @if ($errors->has('username'))
          <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <label for="password" class="control-label">Your desired password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="">
      @if ($errors->has('password'))
          <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

  </form>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
  public function postSignup(Request $request)
 {
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
    'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|max:20',
    'password' => 'required|min:6',
  ]);

  User::create([
      'email' => $request->input('email'),
      'username' => $request->input('username'),
      'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'Your account has been created and you can now sign in!');
```

}

Comment: did you make sure your `username` field declared as fillable in your eloquent model?

Comment: Apparently I just put 'name' this has been fixed and can confirm it's working! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to AndrewMalinnkov for the answer!

```
protected $fillable = [
  'username', // <-- Was not set correctly in my model!
  'email',
  'password',
  'first_name',
  'last_name',
  'location',
];
```